# MySQL não instala

Tags: mysql, windows

Estou tentando instalar o MySQL em Windows 10 e é solicitado como requisito o Microsoft Visual C++ 2013. Estou com a última versão do Visual Studio instalada e como consequência foram instaladas também Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 e também o Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

1. Parece estar indisponível no site da Microsoft a versão 2013. Faço a pesquisa, mas não aparece. Alguém sabe se está mesmo indisponível?
2. Com uma versão maior que a 2013 do "Microsoft Visual C++" a instalação do MySQL não deveria funcionar também?

Comment: Você já utilizou o web plataform installer da microsoft?

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, porém neste instalador também não aparece a versão 2013 na lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Parece estar indisponível no site da Microsoft a versão 2013. Faço a pesquisa, mas não aparece. Alguém sabe se está mesmo indisponível?

Tem vários *links* fora do ar dessa versão, mas encontrei o *link* abaixo onde você pode baixar o *Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable* (`VC12`) mais atualizado:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179560/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package

> 2. Com uma versão maior que a 2013 do "Microsoft Visual C++" a instalação do MySQL não deveria funcionar também?

Ter uma versão *major* mais nova não é suficiente. O MySQL quando foi compilado utilizou essa versão que tem algumas dependências específicas daquela versão do compilador. Encontrei [nesse fórum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/725e66d7-5397-45cc-9360-e1455021cdb7/administrating-the-ms-vc-redistributable-installations?forum=vcgeneral) algumas informações complementares.

Essa dependência até que é normal, com o tempo o *codebase* é atualizado para usar uma versão mais recente. O PHP por exemplo, até a versão 5.6 usa o `VC11` (*Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable*), já o PHP 7.0 e 7.1 usam o `VC14` (*Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable*).

Sobre a preocupação com as atualizações, o MySQL 8 [vai depender do `VC14`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html), sendo uma versão mais nova terá maiores chances dele já estar instalado.

Comment: Obrigado @gmsantos. Instalou perfeitamente a versão 2013 e o MySQL também instalou sem problemas agora. Sobre o item 2, é uma coisa meio tosca do MySQL. Afinal, se está na dependência da Microsoft e esta, por sua vez, não tem que manter compatibilidade com ninguém, então o MySQL deveria prever isso, pois caso contrário ficará impossível instalá-lo em algum momento. Por enquanto vamos tocando...